# Rename symbolic variable - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to rename a symbolic variable in Matlab. Hence is it possible to make it easily? I have already used char(.) or string(.) on it, but without success.

Best regards,
Bruno

--
Post editted:

Some code insight:

```
>> a_sym = sym('a');
>> a_sym

a_sym =

a

>> % Code to change variable here - a_sym = sym('a2'); is not a valid answer
>> a_sym

a_sym =

a2
```

In other words:

```
function new_var = change_symname(var_, suffix)
     new_var = magic_func(var_, suffix);
end
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Could you provide some code to give more insight on what your problem is?

Comment: I completed what you requested, sir.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you are trying to achieve and why this does not work. "_I have access to the variable but not as explicit as in this example_", so show in what way you can access the variable.

Comment: I have changed the variable as requested

Comment: Your proposed function does not take an input argument to know what to change the variable name to, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I provide what you request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subs` to substitute the variable:

```
>> a_sym = sym('a')
a_sym =
a
>> a2_sym = sym('a2')
a2_sym =
a2
>> a_sym = subs(a_sym, a2_sym)
a_sym =
a2
```

---

If you just want to add a suffix, you can do the following. Make sure `suffix` is a `char` array.

```
a_sym = sym('a');
a_sym = change_symname(a_sym, '2')

function new_var = change_symname(var_, suffix)
    new_var = sym([char(var_) suffix]);
end
```

Comment: I don't know the name of the variable. "a" is just a placebo name.

Comment: Do you not know the name of the _symbolic variable_ or the name of the variable that refers to the symbolic variable?

Comment: I have access to the variable but not as explicit as in this example. Consider, for instance, it is a variable provided by a function.